# How do I remove all files that match a pattern?

Tags: command-line, delete

When I revert in Mercurial, it leaves several `.orig` files. I would like to be able to run a command to remove all of them.

I have found some sources that say to run:

```
rm **/*.orig
```

But that gives me the message:

```
rm: cannot remove `**/*.orig': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried these commands:

```
rm -rv *.orig
rm -R *\.orig
```

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/a/699287/92334

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Use the `find` command (with care!)

```
find . -name '*.orig' #-delete
```

I've commented out the delete command but once you're happy with what it's matching, just remove the `#` from the line and it should delete all those files.

Comment: Definitely leave the `-delete` at the _end_ of the flags. `find . -delete -name '*.orig'` will ignore the filter and clobber your whole directory.

Comment: How to take patterns from file i.e. `.gitignore`

Comment: @kyb It sounds like you want `git clean`. Maybe with `-i` or `-n` for safety?

Comment: @Michael, yes. I already solved the problem with `git clean -fdx`

Comment: `find -type f ...` will prevent the warnings if a (non empty) dir happens to have a name like `*.orig`.

Answer (score 26):

"find" has some very advanced techniques to search through all or current directories and rm files.

```
find ./ -name ".orig" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: What's the benefit over using `-delete`?

Comment: @muru I suppose you'd get a prompt for each file if you remove -rf.

Comment: @Peter not necessarily. Even then, so? The answer uses `-rf`, and `find` has `-ok`.

Comment: @muru it looks like -delete does not remove folders

Comment: @AndriiKaraivanskyi unless the deletion failed, it does.

Comment: `rm -rf` will delete recursively directories, then `find` might try to navigate through deleted folders (errors displayed). Also, not sure OP wants to delete `.orig` directories that are likely to include files which are not `.orig`...

Comment: I sign up to this site just that I could upvote this answer. The accepted answer didn't work, but this did the trick for me. Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 13):

I have removed all files that starts with .nfs000000000 like this

```
rm .nfs000000000*
```

Answer (score 7):

The below is what I would normally do

```
find ./ -name "*.orig" | xargs rm -r
```

It's a good idea to check what files you'll be deleting first by checking the `xargs`. The below will print out the files you've found.

```
find ./ -name "*.orig" | xargs
```

If you notice a file that's been found that you don't want to delete either tweak your initial `find` or add a `grep -v` step, which will omit a match, ie

```
find ./ -name "*.orig" | grep -v "somefiletokeep.orig" | xargs rm -r
```

Comment: It's prudent to list all found files first & a nice way to single out any outliers